Power BI RANKX with filter and calculate max causing circular dependency
I'm wondering if anyone can help me overcome a little problem I'm experiencing with RANKX in power bi.
I have a table of data with a couple of columns containing duplicate values,
I want to apply a rank number to each value in the table, with the idea of being able to be filter the column on rank "1", which should if my logic is correct, show me all the unique data,
I've added an index column to the table to allow me to rank against,
There are over 5 million rows of data in my table, below is a sample of the data table where I have filtered the HUB_ID on 2 specific duplicate values (just for the purposes of this exercise):
enter image description here



HUB_ID
GUI_ID
SERIAL_NUMBER
Index




NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z12N019671
669


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z17QF45418
670


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S00282861356
667


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
A381152754
665


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
BB419120518647
666


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S02944911660
668


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z13N030887
58427


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z17QU39570
58428


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S01384441356
58425


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S12053371756
58426


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
A051339939
58423


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
BB216521385155
58424



the above shows rows with the duplicated data against the HUB_ID, so what I'm looking for is to apply a ranking to the index based on the HUB_ID.
so that I get the following:
enter image description here



HUB_ID
GUI_ID
SERIAL_NUMBER
Index
RANK




NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z12N019671
669
5


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z17QF45418
670
6


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S00282861356
667
3


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
A381152754
665
1


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
BB419120518647
666
2


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S02944911660
668
4


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z13N030887
58427
5


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z17QU39570
58428
6


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S01384441356
58425
3


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S12053371756
58426
4


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
A051339939
58423
1


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
BB216521385155
58424
2



Apologies that I've not sorted the RANK column into numerical order but hopefully you can understand what I'm attempting to do all the same :o)
The data sits in a table called Macquarie-Database and I have attempted to create a new column with the following:
RANK =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'Macquarie-Database',
        'Macquarie-Database'[HUB_ID] = EARLIER ( 'Macquarie-Database'[HUB_ID] )
    ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Macquarie-Database'[Index] ) ),
    ,
    ASC,
    SKIP
)

However I keep getting the error "A circular dependency was detected: Macquarie-Database[RANK]"
I've used RANKX in exactly same way in other power bi reports which has worked fine, so i'm scratching my head as to why suddenly now I'm getting the error.
Maybe there's a better way to do what I need, I don't know but was hoping that you good people on the forum may be able to help me sort out my rank? :o)
Any help at this initial stage would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance
Regards
I have tried:
RANK =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'Macquarie-Database',
        'Macquarie-Database'[HUB_ID] = EARLIER ( 'Macquarie-Database'[HUB_ID] )
    ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Macquarie-Database'[Index] ) ),
    ,
    ASC,
    SKIP
)

However I keep getting the error "A circular dependency was detected: Macquarie-Database[RANK]"
This has worked successfully with previous reports, however for some reason with this latest report I'm getting the error message.
I'm hoping to get a RANK column on the end of my table which ranks (ASCENDING) as per the index value against a HUB_ID:
When this didn't work I then tried:
How to generate rank in Power BI on the basis of two column
RANK_HUB_ID =
RANKX (
    ALL ( 'Macquarie-Database' ),
    'Macquarie-Database'[HUB_ID],
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)

which produced:
enter image description here



HUB_ID
GUI_ID
SERIAL_NUMBER
Index
RANK_HUB_ID




NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z12N019671
669
240


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z17QF45418
670
240


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S00282861356
667
240


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
A381152754
665
240


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
BB419120518647
666
240


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S02944911660
668
240


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z13N030887
58427
20984


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z17QU39570
58428
20984


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S01384441356
58425
20984


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S12053371756
58426
20984


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
A051339939
58423
20984


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
BB216521385155
58424
20984



and then created a new column with the following:
RANK =
VAR X =
    MAX ( 'Macquarie-Database'[RANK_HUB_ID] )
VAR RESULT =
    RANKX (
        ALL ( 'Macquarie-Database' ),
        'Macquarie-Database'[Index] * X + 'Macquarie-Database'[RANK_HUB_ID],
        ,
        ASC
    )
RETURN
    RESULT

However, this results in the following:
enter image description here



HUB_ID
GUI_ID
SERIAL_NUMBER
Index
RANK_HUB_ID
RANK




NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z12N019671
669
240
669


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
Z17QF45418
670
240
670


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S00282861356
667
240
667


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
A381152754
665
240
665


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
BB419120518647
666
240
666


NDPD0001564
F8-E5-CF-00-10-21-B0-2A
E6S02944911660
668
240
668


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z13N030887
58427
20984
58427


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
Z17QU39570
58428
20984
58428


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S01384441356
58425
20984
58425


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
E6S12053371756
58426
20984
58426


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
A051339939
58423
20984
58423


NDPD0042939
F8-E5-CF-00-10-0C-1C-98
BB216521385155
58424
20984
58424



So I'm really not sure now where to go with this :o(
Can anyone help please?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Power BI forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Where/How you are generating the INDEX column?

Hi mkRabbani, i generated an index column through "edit query", edit query > add column > index column > from 1

Is this what you want?
Rank2 = RANKX(FILTER(demo, demo[HUB_ID] = EARLIER(demo[HUB_ID])), demo[Index], , ASC)
See results in the photo attached
https://i.sstatic.net/Jfc1in52.png

I think that is exactly what I've been looking for BananaAI :o) so are you telling me that all I had to do was to remove the CALCULATE(MAX ... well I don't believe it (banging my head against the wall), can't thank you enough, your help and support has been absolutely fantastic, much appreciated, regards
